# Concurrent Session in Angular 8 and .Net core API

Tags: .net, angular, .net-core

I have requirement to show popup to Browser A(You are sign in on Browser B and logout in Browser A in 5 sec ) when user try to login on Browser B he should get popup(You are sign in on Browser A and sign in Browser B in 5 sec ) with all details like IP Address

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use session storage for this, as the two browsers will have different sessions.

You can however store details in a database.

On login, store details for this identity about IP address, browser string etc. Plus a "logged in" date and a "last seen" date that you keep updated. And also an (initially empty) "logged out" date.

After login, also check whether that identity is already noted as "logged in", by checking any previous stored details. You will need to decide when you consider someone to be "logged out" - for instance when that user is not seen in the last 20 minutes. Remember that not everyone logs out explicitly.
Now you can show the message stating that the user was already logged in elsewhere.

On every request you will have to update the "last seen" date. And also you will need to check the "logged out" date. If that has a value, you can show the message stating that the current session has been taken over by the other browser (and of course, log out here).